# Can not open the package designer in visual studio 2010

Tags: 2010, visual-studio, solution-package

I can not open the package designer in a SharePoint project.
When I double-click Package or when I right-click Package and then select "View designer" then the XML file Package.package is displayed.
What sould I do to open the package designer ?

Any will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try navigate to "View" on the top menu, then "Other Windows" --> "Packaging Explorer", so you can check that your Package has not been damaged

Comment: The package is present in the packaging explorer. But when I double-click the package or when I right-click the package and then select "View designer" then the XML file Package.package is displayed.

Comment: A message in VS2010 warns me I have to install SharePoint Server or SharePoint Foundation to work with my SharePoint project. I do not think I can install SharePoint because I have got a 32bit processor. Is it possible to use the package designer and generate a WSP package without installing SharePoint ?

Comment: Not that I am aware of, maybee with some hacking